# Replacing a potentiometer with a digital one: Appropriate Pins

Tags: microcontroller, potentiometer

I have this control panel with a 3-pin potentiometer that extrudes from the front as a twistable adjustment. It would be very cool to swap it out with a digital one therefore facilitating the same adjustment from a microcontroller. Avoiding a silly mistake is priority alpha (I'm a software guy.)

Physical pot has: 1, 2, and 3.
Digital 10K pot has: RH, RL, RW, and V+ (V+ bias is connected to RH)

I took measurements from the energized circuit in an effort to identify where the 3 pins on the PCB will map to on the digital one, which is where I need assistance.

> Full Counterclockwise
> 4.7v between pins 1 and 2
> 0v between pins 2 and 3
>
>  
> Full Clockwise:
> 0v between pins 1 and 2 
> -4.5v between pins 2 and 3

It is worth mentioning that the load is negligible because it is an analog signal and the digital pot will support the pull.

Help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Relative to the 0 volts of the power supply, what are the voltages?

Comment: At full counterclockwise (lowest adjustment), the voltage between pin 1 and 0v is 5v. Between pin 2 and 0v is 0v (same for pin 3).

Comment: If the pot is only there to provide a DC voltage between 0V and 5V it might be easier to just use an A/D output from a microcontroller directly.

Comment: Not a bad idea the only issue is I do not know the rest of the circuitry so in my opinion the best thing to do is follow the original design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if your pin 1 is at 5v permanently, your pin 3 is at zero, and pin 2 is the wiper which can run between 5v (counterclockwise) and zero (clockwise). You may want to check that.

Assuming this is correct, then pin 1 = RH (and V+ ), pin 2 is RW, pin 3 is RL. You can check this on https://learn.adafruit.com/ds3502-i2c-potentiometer/pinouts

Comment: After checking, your answer checks out. Using a 10k resistor between pins 1 and 2; and a 1k resistor between 2 and 3, the circuit behaves as if an adjustment was made. Marking your answer as solved.